# using foursquare api v2 to get herenow of a venue

Tags: api, foursquare

on the documentation page, https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues, it says that

> The Venues Platform lets developers use foursquare as their location
>   layer. Applications can search our database and find information
>   including tips, photos, check-in counts, and here now. Searches can be
>   done near a point or through a whole city, and they can be restricted
>   to trending or recommended places. The platform offers all of this
>   without requiring end user authentication and is available at high
>   rate limits.

however, when i send request like:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4ad7a112f964a520050d21e3/herenow?client_id=myclientid&client_secret=myclientsecret&v=20120119

i got this:

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"response":{"hereNow":{"count":16,"items":[]}}}
```

is there anything i need to do, such as register as a venue platform developer, to get the list of people who are here? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the users information without authenticating [ :( ]

Check out the documentation at the [herenow](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/herenow) endpoint page.

Specifically the first line:

> Provides a count of how many people are at a given venue. **If the request is user authenticated**, also **returns** a list of **the users** there, friends-first.

Comment: thanks. the documentation is not very clear. my interpretation was it would return a list of users with order difference if user authenticated. the documentation is very clear about checkin counts and checkins though.